# What library is needed for mach-o/nlist.h (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, mach-o

I seem to have trouble finding the correct library to #include  in my source code. Searched all over the web and my manpages... No result :'(

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 3):

On 32-bit platforms, `nlist(3)` is in `libSystem` which is included by default.

On 64-bit platforms, `nlist(3)` does not exist.

Unless you're looking for non-external symbols, you should use `dlsym(3)`.

Comment: There is no nlist_64 function, there is a struct nlist_64, but that's because that data structure is used in more places from the nlist function. As @KennyTM says, in 64-bit platforms it does not exist. Moreover, if you download the libc [source code](http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/Libc/Libc-763.12.tar.gz) from Apple, for 64-bit the whole file (`gen/nlist.c`) implementing nlist is left out with a macro, and there is a comment saying that it will stay like that until code can be modified (it doesn't look adapted to 64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this helps but on my computer nlist.h is in the iPhone SDK.

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/include/mach-o
```